# If-causes with boolean in javascript (Beginners)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Is there a possibility to write this "If" more efficient?

```
if((text.val(“Hello“) == false)&& (text.val(“This“) == true)&&(text.val(“Is“) == false)&&(text).val(“Me“) == false))
{     
  text = "This"
}
```

This “if“ should check, whether a value is set true or not. It should display only the “true“ one. If I make it in this way, I have to make a lot of If’s in order  to have all possibilities. Is there a way to make it more efficient and better? In database all values are boolean.

Comment: javascript!=java

Comment: `.val("Is")` will set the value and What is  `text`?

Comment: What is `text.val("hello")` supposed to do?

Comment: text.val("hello") should look up the value of text.

Comment: .val("Is") looks up, whether the value of "Is" is set up true or not

Answer (score 0):

To test for one of multiple conditions you could use:

```
  var txt = text.val();
  switch(txt){
    case "Hello":
    case "This":
    case "Is":
    case "Me":
    case "Whatever Else":
      text.val("This");
      break;
  }
```

This will allow you to test very simply for multiple conditions and respond accordingly.  In this case it will return true is any of these conditions are true.  To require all would be:

```
if (txt=="This" && txt=="Hello" && txt=="Is" && txt=="Me"){...}
```

This is the only way to test that all conditions are true, unless you want to use arrays and a true-false marker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused as to how `.val()` works.  If the parameter is left empty, it returns the value.  If it has a parameter, it sets the value. ([jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/))  If I read your `if` statement correctly, it will only execute if the value of the text is equal to `"This"`.  This could be simplified by the following:

```
if(text.val() == “This“) {     
    text.val("This");
}
```

In case you wanted your statement rewritten, here is how it might look:

```
if((text.val() != “Hello“) && (text.val() == “This“) && (text.val() != “Is“) && (text).val() != “Me“))
{     
  text.val("This");
}
```

I would also recommend looking through the documentation in link above and even looking through [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is an efficient way without jQuery or other library:

```js
var text = "Hello This Is Me";
var textSplit = text.split(' ');
var count = textSplit.length;

for(i=0;i<=count;i++){
  if(textSplit[i] == 'This'){
     text = 'This';
     alert(text);
     break;
  }
}
```